# Installing php5-cgi

Tags: php, installation

I am trying to install a new LEMP (Linux,Nginx,MySQL and PHP).  Everything I have read says that in order to use PHP's Fast CGI to just run "yum install php5-cgi".  I am running this from an Amazon EC2 instance and it just tells me that php5-cgi is not available.  I have also tried downloading the source php5 package and running "./configure --with-php5-cgi and it finishes but says:
Notice: Following unknown configure options were used:
--with-php5-cgi

Any help on what I am doing wrong?  I have seen installs using lighthttp's fastcgi but it seems that most recommend you use php's built in version.

Link with the install instructions I am following: [link](http://tomasz.sterna.tv/2009/04/php-fastcgi-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Yum should provide php5-fcgi for you. If not, do you have the necessary repository enabled? The instructions you provided are for Ubuntu, and working yum suggests you're on CentOS or something? What distro do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I am testing with Amazon's EC2 free instance which is not labeled CentOS but I agree since yum is working its a form of CentOS.  I tried php5-fcgi and I get the same message: Notice: Following unknown configure options were used: --with-php5-fcgi.  I am running a configure using the PHP5 source code which I downloaded, is there a special additional repository I need?

Comment: I would really prefer if I could just get yum install php5-cgi working instead of having to download the source but I wasn't sure how to adjust the repository to find it.

Comment: Yes, possible in the link I answered - yum install php stuff, then yum install spawn-fcgi stuff. Check the doc out.